# Display menu elements according to page_number and page_size

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to simulate a menu ready for displays with 4 rows..The menu items are dynamically populated and I tried this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  #define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20

  char OPTIONS[12][20] = {
      "MenuItem1",
      "MenuItem2",
      "MenuItem3",
      "MenuItem4",
      "MenuItem5",
      "MenuItem6",
      "MenuItem7",
      "MenuItem8",
      "MenuItem9",
      "MenuItem10",
      "MenuItem11",
      "MenuItem12"
  };

  int OPTIONS_LENGTH = 12;
  int PAGE_SIZE = 4;
  int PAGE_NUMBER = 1;

  void ShowSelected(int _index){
      if(_index > (PAGE_SIZE * PAGE_NUMBER)){
          PAGE_NUMBER++;
      }else if(_index < (PAGE_SIZE * PAGE_NUMBER) && PAGE_NUMBER > 1){ // here seems to be an issue when the page number should be decreased
        PAGE_NUMBER--;
      }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++) {
        char finalString[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        strcpy(finalString, _index == i ? ">" : " ");
        strcat(finalString, OPTIONS[i]);
        printf("\n %s", finalString);
    }

    printf("\n-------------");
    printf("\nselected_item: %d | page_number: %d", _index + 1, PAGE_NUMBER);
    printf("\n-------------");
  }

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        ShowSelected(i);
    }
    
     for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
        ShowSelected(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is to show a range of 4 elements (with one marked as selected (according to selected index)) from the options array according to PAGE_NUMBER

The expected output should be:

```
 >MenuItem1                                                                                           
  MenuItem2                                                                                           
  MenuItem3                                                                                           
  MenuItem4                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 1 | page_number: 1                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem1                                                                                           
 >MenuItem2                                                                                           
  MenuItem3                                                                                           
  MenuItem4                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 2 | page_number: 1                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem1                                                                                           
  MenuItem2                                                                                           
 >MenuItem3                                                                                           
  MenuItem4                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 3 | page_number: 1                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem1                                                                                           
  MenuItem2                                                                                           
  MenuItem3                                                                                           
 >MenuItem4                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 4 | page_number: 1 
-------------   
 >MenuItem5                                                                                           
  MenuItem6                                                                                           
  MenuItem7                                                                                           
  MenuItem8                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 5 | page_number: 2                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem5                                                                                           
 >MenuItem6                                                                                           
  MenuItem7                                                                                           
  MenuItem8                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 6 | page_number: 2                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem5                                                                                           
  MenuItem6                                                                                           
 >MenuItem7                                                                                           
  MenuItem8                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 7 | page_number: 2                                                                     
-------------                                                                                         
  MenuItem5                                                                                          
  MenuItem6                                                                                           
  MenuItem7                                                                                           
 >MenuItem8                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                         
selected_item: 8 | page_number: 2 

.
.
.
```

Is there someone that can help me to fix this, or if someone has a better idea?

**EDIT**
Current output:

```
 >MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 1 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
 >MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 2 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
 >MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 3 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
 >MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 4 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 5 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 6 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 7 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 8 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 9 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 10 | page_number: 3
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 11 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 12 | page_number: 3
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 13 | page_number: 3
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 12 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 11 | page_number: 3
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 10 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 9 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 8 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 7 | page_number: 2
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 6 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 5 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
 >MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 4 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
  MenuItem2
 >MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 3 | page_number: 1
-------------
  MenuItem1
 >MenuItem2
  MenuItem3
  MenuItem4
-------------
selected_item: 2 | page_number: 1
-------------
```

Comment: You have shown code and expected output. What is the output you get? What is the difference? What did you try to pinpoint the problem in your code?

Comment: I updated the post with the actual output of the code... After the first 4 selections, the page number isn't increased/decreased correctly and in the code, I left a comment on the if condition where I think the code is broken...

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger and see where it goes wrong? There is at least one bug here: `strcat(finalString, OPTIONS[i]);` (you should take the page number into account) but there might be more.

Comment: You calculate `PAGE_NUMBER`, but then never use it.

Comment: And `PAGE_NUMBER` can easily be calculated as `PAGE_NUMBER = _index / PAGE_SIZE;`